# HD5850 scoring a 6.0 Windows Experience score

Tags: amd-radeon, benchmarking, windows-experience-index

I just reformatted my computer. Prior to doing so, my base-line windows user experience score was a 7.6, with 7.7's in both of the graphics categories. After completing my reformat, I installed the latest catalyst drivers (01/27/2009, v10.1). However, I'm scoring a 6.0 in both of the graphics categories, and the device manager has my drivers dated at 12/11/2009, v8.69.

The drivers seem to go in cleanly, other than that. I get no error, and I rebooted after installing them. What might be causing this performance bottleneck?

I'm running Windows 7, 64-bit enterprise. I have an i920 @3.6GHz, an XFX Radeon 5850, and 6GB of RAM.

Comment: No idea. There could be a variety of problems, not just driver related. I'm not familiar enough with the WES to offer an answer.

Comment: 6.0? i just installed Windows 7 on a Eee 701 4G and scored a breathtaking 1.0 ... Intel GMA 915 FTW! :)

Comment: Molly, my 701 4G has a 4GB ssd. Would love to hear how you managed that (offline of course)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have all the latest drivers for the motherboard(chipset)? Having great graphics doesn't matter if the CPU can't communicate with them effectively.

Comment: No, I most certainly do not! Good call.

Comment: chipset drivers make a HUGE difference [usually]

Comment: Graphics are reading 7.7 now. Thanks!